# Throwing OutOfMemoryError on create Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have a custom Android device with an LCD screen. It can draw bitmaps.  I prepare them from Android views.

```
private Bitmap loadBitmapFromView() {
    if ((mView.getVisibility() != VISIBLE) ||
            (mView.getMeasuredWidth() <= 0) ||
            (mView.getMeasuredHeight() <= 0)) return null;
    Bitmap b;
    if ((mView instanceof ImageView) && !(mView instanceof ImageButton)) {
        BitmapDrawable drawable = ((BitmapDrawable) ((ImageView) mView).getDrawable());
        if (drawable == null) return null;
        b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(drawable.getBitmap().copy(drawable.getBitmap().getConfig(), true),
                mView.getMeasuredWidth(), mView.getMeasuredHeight(), false);
    } else {
        b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mView.getMeasuredWidth(), mView.getMeasuredHeight(), ARGB_8888);
    }
    replaceColor(b, ColorChannel.ALPHA, 0, mBackgroundColor);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    mView.layout(mLocation.x - mParentLocation.x, mLocation.y - mParentLocation.y,
            mLocation.x - mParentLocation.x + mView.getMeasuredWidth(),
            mLocation.y - mParentLocation.y + mView.getMeasuredHeight());
    mView.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

ARGB_8888 used here because some views have transparency.

After some time of usage, it stops to draw.

I added `android:largeHeap="true"` and `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` to Manifest and got OOM

```
12-17 11:19:32.591 15169-15169/com.appcard.androidterminal E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 614412 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 244MB until OOM"
12-17 11:19:32.619 15169-15169/com.appcard.androidterminal E/Surface: dequeueBuffer failed (Function not implemented)
12-17 11:19:32.620 15169-15169/com.appcard.androidterminal E/ViewRootImpl: Could not lock surface
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
        at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:264)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2998)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2966)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2753)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1292)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6598)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I tried to recycle bitmap after drawing, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of memory limitations. You can load scaled down version of your bitmap.

Follow documentation here to know more about how to efficiently load bitmaps

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

Comment: In this example, they scale bitmaps taken from resources. How to scale down bitmap taken from view in my case?

Answer (score 0):

I solved OutOfMemory issues by replacing `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` and `imageView.setImageResource(imageRes)` with Glide:
https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/targets.html

Comment: I don't load the bitmap to image view. I need it to draw on a separate LCD screen after.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(view.getDrawingCache(), width, height, false);
```

Here view is the view that you want to draw, width and height are the output width and height.

If the problem still persist, you may reduce the size of the bitmap by a factor of 2 or so. Secondly if you are handling multiple bitmaps, you may do it one by one so that there are only one or two bitmaps in the memory that are really required.

Comment: still throwing OOM. any more ideas?

Comment: Reduce width and height further by a factor width = width/2. Check other parts of app as well